# Guzzle argument with [] fail to recognize as array

Tags: php, arrays, guzzle

In a example of oficial documentation of Guzzle:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', ['body' => 'testing...']);
```

But:

> "Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given"

PHP version: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli)

Is the version of PHP or the code lack of something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like argument 3 must be an `array` try

```
$request = $client->createRequest('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', array('body' => 'testing...'));
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) about arrays and its structuring

Comment: The error is the same. The docs: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/psr7.rst

Comment: The error is the same. More OFICIAL examples: $request = new Psr7\Request('GET', '/', ['X-Foo' => 'bar']);

Comment: I think that the doc is old and deprecated.

Comment: @marioquartz most likely. Edit the ans or add yours. might help others.